# Apply CSS animation to every element of the array

Tags: jquery, css-animations

I want to display a div where the text transitions and changes every 4 seconds. I have got the text to change after every four seconds, but the animation is not getting applied. How to fix this issue?

Here is the js fiddle with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/zm1dxybr/2/

CSS:

```
.fadeInDownExit{
    -webkit-animation: fadeInDownExit 8s linear alternate;
    -o-animation: fadeInDownExit 8s linear alternate;
    animation: fadeInDownExit 8s linear alternate;
}

@keyframes fadeInDownExit {
    0%, 100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }

    10%, 90% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(20px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(20px);
        -o-transform: translateY(20px);
        transform: translateY(20px);
    }

}
```

jQuery:

```
var text = ["Welcome", "Hi", "Sup dude"];
var counter = 0;
setInterval(change, 4000);
  function change() { 

                        $('#changeText').html(text[counter]).addClass('fadeInDownExit');
   counter++;
   $('#changeText').html(text[counter - 1]).removeClass('fadeInDownExit');
   if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
  }
```

Comment: Have you seen error in console

Comment: no there are no errors. Just the animation is not getting applied

Comment: Is class is changing check with inspect element

Comment: That's not how CSS animations work.

Comment: @YasarArafath - class is getting applied again and again, just the inner html is changing.

Comment: @Mr. Alien you trying to say something will you brief

Comment: You need not to add and remove class for animation, please see I have updated js. jsfiddle link provided in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>toggleClass demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>
  div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
  .big-blue {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #00f;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div></div>
 
<script>
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "big-blue", 1000, "easeOutSine" );
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is look like in your code removing the class name is happening immediately, try to use the following code:

```html
var text = ["Welcome", "Hi", "Sup dude"];
var counter = 0;
var intervalstop;
setInterval(change, 8000);
function change() { 
  $('#changeText').html(text[counter]).addClass('fadeInDownExit');
  counter++;
  intervalstop = setInterval(removepclass, 4002);
  if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
   }
   
 function removepclass() {
   clearInterval(intervalstop);
   $('#changeText').removeClass('fadeInDownExit'); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this works perfect

```
var text = ["Welcome", "Hi", "Sup dude"];
var counter = 0;
setInterval(change, 4000);
function change() {
 $('#changeText').html(text[counter]).toggleClass('fadeInDownExit');
 counter++;
 $('#changeText').html(text[counter - 1]);
 if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the js as we don't need to add class every time for animation:

```
var text = ["Welcome", "Hi", "Sup dude"];
var counter = 0;
setInterval(change, 4000);
function change() {

    $('#changeText').html(text[counter % text.length]);
  counter++;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zm1dxybr/5/

Comment: It isn't applying the transition to all the elements.

Comment: It is working for all the elements in the text array,please see in the jsfiddle link  , and what are `all the elements` by the way?